# Does the Tanya tzadik exist?

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, chabad, chassidic-rebbe, tanya

Does the Tanya's tzadik really exist nowadays?
If yes, why? And who can it be?
If no, why?

To what extent did the Lubavitcher Rebbe correspond to the Tanya's description of the tzadik?

Comment: I'm not sure the Rebbe gives us instructions on how to spot a Tzaddik in Tanya. It's there to explain the purpose and missions of life.

Comment: @RabbiKaii but do you think that he correspond to the tanya's tzadik

Comment: Yes I believe he said so, and I personally have no reason to doubt it so I believe it. In much of the orthodox world he was considered a generational tzaddik

Comment: Related: "[Was Moshe a Tanya-tzadik?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35554/1368)"

Comment: None of us are qualified to assess a soul of that caliber, but the Rebbe referred to [R' Zalman Moshe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zalman_Moishe_HaYitzchaki) as a Tzaddik. Many Lubavitchers would consider it an understatement applied to the Rebbe.

Comment: The real question is, who is truly a Beinoni?

Comment: @TheTargum it is said on a tomchei tmimim brunoy mashpia that during his tefillah he isa  beinoni

Comment: isn't there the idea of the ל"ו tzadikim and other ideas on tzadikim, so I'd say yes there are tzadikim of what is mentioned in tanya. (I don't have sources for you though. I'm not versed in this subject) and for the Rebbe who is the נשמע כללי and נשי הדור that He is definitely a tzadik as well (it's inclusive and a given).

Comment: Aren't there individuals who the Rebbe told them, "you are finished the avoda of Beinoni, now is time to do the avoda of "tzadik"? see https://insidechassidus.org