# how can Adam Harishon be a tanya tsadik?

Tags: sin, chasidut-hasidism, adam, tzaddikim, tanya

the *Alter Rebbe* teaches in the **Tanya** that the ***true tzadik*** does not commit **averot** (sin)
it is explained (in chapter 10 it seems to me) that the beinoni does not commit **any avera** then ***a fortiori the tsadik***
so how according on the fact that a tzadik does not make a mistake *(as we can see in the tanya)* we can explain that Adam Harishon (who is apparently a tzadik) committed an avera
(moreover it is explained in the chassidus and kabala that the sin of Adam Harishon was to want to be at a level of creator like G.O.D who can create from nothing meayin leyesh I don't know if this precision is useful but that shows that the fault was quite serious)

I know that the question was also asked for moshe rabenou I saw a midrash that could give the answer of the midrash explaining that moshe rabenu was forced by Hashem for the sin of the rock.
moreover the sin of the rock was not a "real sin", but only a sin at the level of moshe... perhaps it is the same thing for adam

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/35554/was-moshe-a-tanya-tzadik?rq=1
this is the related question on moshe

Comment: Where does it say Adam was a tzaddik?

Comment: @shmosel he had a neshama klalis I don't think it's possible without being a tzadik
https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/adam-harishon-his-divine-level/
rashbi is obviously a tzadik

Comment: It is very important to note that when Adam committed the sin, he had no yeitzer hara. See this maamar: https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/3140460/jewish/page.htm for more information about what was going on in Gan Eden on a deeper level.

Comment: @RabbiKaii thank you so much 
I will learn this maamer but just for a quick answer how can he sin with no yetzer hara?
and to understand the yetzer hara existed already, the snake was the yetzer hara but not like nowadays like he was outside of the creature

Comment: @L770 The fact is, he didn't have a yeitzer hara (and never had one - it was born to his and Chava's children), so therefore is definitely a Tanya Tzaddik. A sin came about through him, it is true, but not from his yeizter hara, so it is something different. The maamar will explain that the sin that he did was actually meant to happen, for example, so we are not discussing a regular sin.

Comment: @RabbiKaii thank you so much